# React: Filter to get only duplicate values ​from an Array

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json

In this Array all the idCategory of **"answersTo"** are obtained, some duplicates. I need to filter so that it returns only this, the duplicates. Normally I would filter if I have data to compare, but not here.

```
{
  previewData.map((getPrev: any, index: any) =>
    getPrev.answers.map((getAns: any) => {
      getAns.answersTo.map((getAnsTo: any) =>
        console.log("data", getAnsTo.idCategoria)
      );
    })
  );
 }
```

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: added screenshot of result which I want to get. The only identical 5 results.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "I would filter if I have data to compare, but not here."

Comment: @Apostolos I could do a .filter(item => datamap === parameterGetted) but I don't have that parameter to compare

Comment: It is totally unclear what you want to do here. Please provide the sample data and expected output)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have an array and you need to filter it to return only the duplicate values. Here is how you can do this:

```js
    function duplicates(arr) {
        let seen = {};
        return arr.filter(function(item) {
            if (seen.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
                return true;
            }
    
            seen[item] = true
            return false;
        });
    }
    
    console.log(duplicates([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4])) // Outputs [1, 4]
```